# Cut off excerpt from excerpt box in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to use `the_excerpt()` from the excerpt box. I have a filter to control the number of words that should appear. While this works if the excerpt is taken from the content area, it fails to work if its taken from the excerpt box in the post editor.

I would like to either 
a: take the excerpt from the content area so the cut off works like normal.

OR

b: use the excerpt from the excerpt box but be able to apply a cut off.

```
function custom_excerpt_length() {
global $myExcerptLength;

if ($myExcerptLength) {
  return $myExcerptLength;
  } 
else {
  return 25; //default value
}
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length');
```

And in my template...

```
<div class="blog-post-excerpt">

<?php   $myExcerptLength=30;
        the_excerpt();
        $myExcerptLength=20;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used my own workaround...

```
echo substr(strip_tags(get_the_content()),0,180).'...';
```

instead of the `the_excerpt()`